# Can I have that A-Z index bar in an UITableView also with UITableViewStyleGrouped, or only with UITableViewStylePlain?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Can I have that A-Z index bar in an UITableView also with UITableViewStyleGrouped, or only with UITableViewStylePlain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhone Human Interface Guidelines state that with UITableViewStyleGrouped: "This style of table view does not provide an index."